# How to move (excel) files into a directory after selecting it from fileChooser and adding it to tableview (javafx)

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to add a selected excel file from `fileChooser` into a directory and then display it into a table (`TableView`). I had something that would previously add the file into the directory but then the excel file would end up corrupted. Even when I did have the files moved manually (*so that the file wouldn't be corrupt*), the table would not properly display the file name.

It just looked like this:

[image]
(*Ignore the second table I haven't done anything with that yet. Pressing `Add Excel File` opens up file explorer and displays only excel files. The first table is taking in files from a directory and starts up but then the name of the file doesn't show. Only a highlight indicating that something might be there.*)

```
TableView<File> files = new TableView();
TableColumn sheets = new TableColumn();
files.getColumns().add(sheets);
files.getItems().addAll(sSheets.listFiles());
optionsWind.add(files, 0, 1);

Label tLabel = new Label("Your Templates");
optionsWind.add(tLabel, 1, 0);

TableView<File> template = new TableView();
TableColumn t = new TableColumn();
t.getColumns().add(t);
template.getItems().addAll(templates.listFiles());
optionsWind.add(template, 1, 1);

//Buttons grid
GridPane buttons = new GridPane();
buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
buttons.setVgap(20);

//excel file
Button addFile = new Button();
addFile.setText("Add Excel File");
buttons.add(addFile, 0, 1);
addFile.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
     public void handle(ActionEvent e){                             
         FileChooser excChs = new FileChooser();
         excChs.setTitle("Open Excel File");
         excChs.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Excel Files", "*.xlsx"));
         File selectFile = excChs.showOpenDialog(secondaryStage);

         //add stuff here
}});
```

Comment: Read the file in as bytes.  Write the file as bytes. Save the file in the new location. If the file is successfully saved in the new location, delete the old file.

Comment: To display the excel file in a TableView you will need to start with something like [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: What API are you using to read the Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

You can play with this app to better understand how to save a file in a new location. You should ask your other question on a different thread. There should only be one question to a thread.

One button loads an Excel file. The other button saves the loaded file to a location of your choice and with a name of your choice.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication132 extends Application
{
    byte[] fileContent;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {


        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Load file");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                try 
                {
                    FileChooser excChs = new FileChooser();
                    excChs.setTitle("Open Excel File");
                    excChs.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Excel Files", "*.xlsx"));
                    File selectFile = excChs.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                    fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(selectFile.toPath());
                    System.out.println("File loaded!");
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }
            }
        });

        Button btnSaveFile = new Button();
        btnSaveFile.setText("Save loaded file");
        btnSaveFile.setOnAction((event)->{
            try 
            {
                FileChooser excChs = new FileChooser();
                excChs.setTitle("Save Excel File");
                excChs.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Excel Files", "*.xlsx"));
                File saveFile = excChs.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
                if(saveFile != null && fileContent.length > 0)
                {
                    Files.write(saveFile.toPath(), fileContent);
                    System.out.println("File saved!");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn, btnSaveFile);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

If you know which directory you want to save your files to, you should hard code it. This example shows how to accomplish this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication132 extends Application
{
    byte[] fileContent;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {


        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Load file");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                try 
                {
                    FileChooser excChs = new FileChooser();
                    excChs.setTitle("Open Excel File");
                    excChs.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Excel Files", "*.xlsx"));
                    File selectFile = excChs.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                    fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(selectFile.toPath());
                    System.out.println("File loaded!");

                    String directoryToSaveFile = "TheAbsolutePathToSavingDirectory";<--Change this
                    File saveFile = new File(directoryToSaveFile + selectFile.getName());
                    if(saveFile.createNewFile())
                    {
                        if(fileContent.length > 0)
                        {
                            Files.write(saveFile.toPath(), fileContent);
                            System.out.println("File saved to " + saveFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("No file was created!");
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }
            }
        });



        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }  
}
```