# Saving text in a Calendar app to a .txt file

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm developing a Calendar app in Java FX that lets users input text into a variety of rows and columns, then lets them save the calendar data to a .txt file.

However, whenever the .txt file is saved and generated, none of my text is being saved, and an empty .txt file is generated. My code is below if anyone can identify any issues or errors going on in the program. The specific method that saves the data to a .txt is `saveCalendarAsText`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CalendarSavingApp extends Application {

    private TextArea[][] dayTextAreas = new TextArea[5][7];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) {
        mainStage.setTitle("Calendar Saving App");
        mainStage.setResizable(true);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18;");

        GridPane calendarGrid = createCalendarGrid();
        VBox box = new VBox(calendarGrid);

        Scene mainScene = new Scene(root);
        mainStage.setScene(mainScene);

        root.setCenter(box);

        Button saveButton = new Button("Save as TXT");

        box.getChildren().add(saveButton);
        VBox.setVgrow(calendarGrid, Priority.ALWAYS);

        saveButton.setOnAction((event) -> saveCalendarAsText(mainStage));

        mainStage.show();
        mainStage.sizeToScene();
    }

    private GridPane createCalendarGrid() {
        GridPane calendarGrid = new GridPane();
        calendarGrid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        calendarGrid.setHgap(5);
        calendarGrid.setVgap(5);

        // Add label for the month at the top center
        Label monthLabel = new Label("December 2023");
        monthLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 36; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
        calendarGrid.add(monthLabel, 3, 0, 4, 1); // Spanning 4 columns

        int dayNumber = 1;
        for (int row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
                if (dayNumber > 31) {
                    // Break if we have reached more than 31 days
                    break;
                }

                if (row == 1 && col < 2) {
                    // Center the first two boxes
                    continue;
                }

                TextArea dayTextArea = new TextArea();
                dayTextArea.setPrefRowCount(3);
                dayTextArea.setPrefColumnCount(12);
                dayTextArea.setEditable(true);  // Set to editable
                dayTextArea.setWrapText(false); // Disable text wrapping
                dayTextAreas[row - 1][col] = dayTextArea;

                String dayOfWeek = calculateDayOfWeek(col + 1);
                String dayString = dayOfWeek + " the " + addOrdinalSuffix(dayNumber);
                dayTextArea.setText(dayString);

                calendarGrid.add(dayTextArea, col, row);

                dayNumber++;
            }
        }

        return calendarGrid;
    }

    private String calculateDayOfWeek(int dayNumber) {
        // Zeller's Congruence algorithm to calculate the day of the week
        int h = (dayNumber + 2 * 12 + 3 * (12 + 1) / 5) % 7;
        switch (h) {
            case 0:
                return "Saturday";
            case 1:
                return "Sunday";
            case 2:
                return "Monday";
            case 3:
                return "Tuesday";
            case 4:
                return "Wednesday";
            case 5:
                return "Thursday";
            case 6:
                return "Friday";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

    private void saveCalendarAsText(Stage mainStage) {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text files", "*.txt");
        chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);

        File file = chooser.showSaveDialog(mainStage);

        if (file == null) {
            return; // User canceled the file chooser
        }

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            // Iterate through all text areas and write data to the text file
            for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
                    String dayData = dayTextAreas[row][col].getText().trim();
                    if (!dayData.isEmpty()) {
                        writer.write(dayData + System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException error) {
            // TODO: Handle the exception and provide user feedback
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String addOrdinalSuffix(int dayNumber) {
        if (dayNumber >= 11 && dayNumber <= 13) {
            return dayNumber + "th";
        } else {
            switch (dayNumber % 10) {
                case 1:
                    return dayNumber + "st";
                case 2:
                    return dayNumber + "nd";
                case 3:
                    return dayNumber + "rd";
                default:
                    return dayNumber + "th";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: Have a look at `btnSaveFile` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782375/2423906)

Comment: Does your code ever reach the line with `writer.write(...` ?

Comment: When I tried running this and pressing the save button, I got `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TextArea.getText()" because "this.dayTextAreas[<local6>][<local7>]" is null`.  Perhaps your saveCalendarAsText method needs to account for the fact that the first and last week of the month may not be a full week and may not have text areas for every day of the week?

Comment: I haven't looked deeply at your code, but I think `if (row == 0 && col < 2) {
                   // Center the first two boxes
                   continue;
               }` is causing some of the in the array to be null. That's my guess.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is caused by

```
if (row == 1 && col < 2) {
    // Center the first two boxes
    continue;
}
```

I did not test it, so I could be wrong, but it looks like it will cause some index(s) to end up with null value(s).

I would use a `List` over `Array` for this since a month can be less than 31 days. I did use an array in this example, but it is a 1D array.

I also noticed that your `Zellercongruence` method could be incorrect. I did not attempt to use your version. I used the version from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zellers-congruence-find-day-date/. Your version returned a `String` of the day of the week. I also added another version that would return an `int` that maps to a day of the week.

The save method prints as the days would show up on the calendar.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App extends Application {

    int DAYS_IN_MONTH = 31;
    
    private final TextArea[] dayTextAreas = new TextArea[DAYS_IN_MONTH];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) {
        mainStage.setTitle("Calendar Saving App");
        mainStage.setResizable(true);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18;");

        GridPane calendarGrid = createCalendarGrid();
        VBox box = new VBox(calendarGrid);

        Scene mainScene = new Scene(root);
        mainStage.setScene(mainScene);

        root.setCenter(box);

        Button saveButton = new Button("Save as TXT");

        box.getChildren().add(saveButton);
        VBox.setVgrow(calendarGrid, Priority.ALWAYS);

        saveButton.setOnAction((event) -> saveCalendarAsText(mainStage));

        mainStage.show();
        mainStage.sizeToScene();
    }

    private GridPane createCalendarGrid() {
        GridPane calendarGrid = new GridPane();
        calendarGrid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        calendarGrid.setHgap(5);
        calendarGrid.setVgap(5);

        // Add label for the month at the top center
        Label monthLabel = new Label("December 2023");
        monthLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 36; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
        calendarGrid.add(monthLabel, 3, 0, 4, 1); // Spanning 4 columns

        int gridRow = 1; 
        for (int zeroDay = 0; zeroDay < DAYS_IN_MONTH; zeroDay++) {
            TextArea dayTextArea = new TextArea();
            dayTextArea.setPrefRowCount(3);
            dayTextArea.setPrefColumnCount(12);
            dayTextArea.setEditable(true);  // Set to editable
            dayTextArea.setWrapText(false); // Disable text wrapping
            dayTextAreas[zeroDay] = dayTextArea;

            String dayOfWeek = Zellercongruence(zeroDay + 1, 12, 2023);
            String dayString = dayOfWeek + " the " + addOrdinalSuffix(zeroDay + 1);
            dayTextArea.setText(dayString);



            int zellerInt = ZellercongruenceAsInt(zeroDay + 1, 12, 2023);
            int gridColumn = ConvertZellerDayToGridColumn(zellerInt);             
            if(gridColumn == 0)
            {
                gridRow++;
            }
            calendarGrid.add(dayTextArea, gridColumn, gridRow);            
        }

        return calendarGrid;
    }

    // Print Day for a Date
    static String Zellercongruence(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        if (month == 1)
        {
            month = 13;
            year--;
        }
        if (month == 2)
        {
            month = 14;
            year--;
        }
        int q = day;
        int m = month;
        int k = year % 100;
        int j = year / 100;
        int h = q + 13*(m + 1) / 5 + k + k / 4 + j / 4 + 5 * j;
        h = h % 7;
        switch (h)
        {
            case 0 : return "Saturday";
            case 1 : return "Sunday"; 
            case 2 : return "Monday";
            case 3 : return "Tuesday";
            case 4 : return "Wednesday";
            case 5 : return "Thursday";
            case 6 : return "Friday";
        }
        
        return "error!";
    }

    static int ZellercongruenceAsInt(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        if (month == 1)
        {
            month = 13;
            year--;
        }
        if (month == 2)
        {
            month = 14;
            year--;
        }
        int q = day;
        int m = month;
        int k = year % 100;
        int j = year / 100;
        int h = q + 13*(m + 1) / 5 + k + k / 4 + j / 4 + 5 * j;
        
        return h % 7;        
    }
    
    static int ConvertZellerDayToGridColumn(int ZellerDay)
    {
        int column = -1;
        
        switch(ZellerDay)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                column = ZellerDay - 1;
                break;
            case 0:
                column = 6;
        }
        
        return column;
    }
    
    private void saveCalendarAsText(Stage mainStage) {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text files", "*.txt");
        chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);

        File file = chooser.showSaveDialog(mainStage);

        if (file == null) {
            return; // User canceled the file chooser
        }

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            // Iterate through all text areas and write data to the text file
            for (int dayZero = 0; dayZero < dayTextAreas.length; dayZero++) {                   
                int zellerInt = ZellercongruenceAsInt(dayZero + 1, 12, 2023);
                int gridColumn = ConvertZellerDayToGridColumn(zellerInt);             
                if(gridColumn == 0)
                {
                    writer.newLine();
                }
                writer.write(dayTextAreas[dayZero].getText() + "\t");
            }
        } catch (IOException error) {
            // TODO: Handle the exception and provide user feedback
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String addOrdinalSuffix(int dayNumber) {
        if (dayNumber >= 11 && dayNumber <= 13) {
            return dayNumber + "th";
        } else {
            switch (dayNumber % 10) {
                case 1:
                    return dayNumber + "st";
                case 2:
                    return dayNumber + "nd";
                case 3:
                    return dayNumber + "rd";
                default:
                    return dayNumber + "th";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Output 1**

[image]

**Output 2**

[image]